# unable to use whatsapp on wifi xiaomi a3 device

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 9.0-pie, xiaomi, mi

I am using Whatsapp on Xiaomi A3 device.
I am unable to use Whatsapp on Wifi of my home. I have a broadband ADSL router. Whose settigngs never changed. There are other people who use Wifi and their whatsapp works perfectly. 
In my case it used to work but now it is giving problems. I am able to use internet using Wifi of my home on this Mi A3 phone.But I am not able to use whatsapp. I mean to say neither any message gets downloaded and neither any message is sent on whatsapp when I am connected to Wifi of my home. But when I switch on my data plan immediately all the messages which are pending to get delivered, in the que get delivered.
Also I receive the pending messages.I restarted the device after a restart I do get my whatsapp usable for 10 minutes on my Wifi. But after some time again the same situation is there.
I am using WhatsApp 2.20.108 (it is not business edition). The phone is android 9,model name M190F9SI.
What should I do?

Comment: Is your device connected to the main Wifi of your router or some sort of guest network? Check the router settings if something is filtered by the router. Also check if in your Android device for your Wifi is configured to use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an X icon bottom-right side of the wifi icon? Try "forget this network" and reconnect. It happened to me a few times and this is how i solved. Check network related whatsapp settings also.